# uncaught reference error:. jspdf is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I have used jsPDF for PDF conversion of tables. In bower_components I have 3 files `Filesaver.js`, `jspdf.js`, and `jspdf.plugin.table.js` files. While my page loads the files are also loading. It is showing this error at the end of `jspdf.plugin.table.js` file pointing (jsPDF.API). In my controller I have the function like this.

```
$scope.exportPdf = function(sampletable, a, b) {    
    var addr = $scope.address;      
    var name = a + ' ' + b; 
    var address = addr; 
    var tbldata = [], 
        fontSize = 8, 
        height = 1, 
        doc;

    doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);
    doc.setFont("times", "normal");
    doc.setFontSize(fontSize);
    doc.text(280, 50,'Hi');
    doc.text(220,80,address);

    tbldata = []; 
    tbldata = doc.tableToJson('sampletable');
    height = doc.drawTable(tbldata, {
        xstart: 10,
        ystart: 10,
        tablestart: 100,
        marginleft: 10,
        xOffset: 15,
        yOffset: 20
    });

    doc.save("mypdf.pdf");      
 }
```

Please help me.

Comment: The error means that you haven't included the JS file which includes the `jsPDF` library, or the path to it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependency files into index file, you should refer the dependency.